# Weird behavior when overriding gnome alert styling?

Tags: unity, gnome, i3-wm

After playing around with the i3 tiling window manager, I had my fill and decided to uninstall it and continue using gnome. However, to my dismay, something in i3 overrode the default gnome alert box. For example, when connecting to wifi, I get a gray or blue box instead of the nice ubuntu popups. The screenshot says it all. Any ideas?

[image]

(See top right corner)

Comment: Was the i3 package a metapackage?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes I believe so

Comment: Did you remove ***everything*** that the metapackage installed?

Comment: yes, that's the weird part. As far as I can tell, this is  some styling in a config file somewhere.

Comment: Could it be, that you somehow replaced your default notification daemon with dunst? `sudo apt-get purge dunst` should remove it.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Unfortunately I can't reward bounties on comments, so Anwar gets the loot. Still, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing i3 and testing with different notification daemons, It's seems that the notification you're receiving are from [`dunst`](http://knopwob.org/dunst/index.html) notification daemon.

Simply removing it should fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove dunst
```

is the command you need to execute in a terminal.

Check the screenshot of dunst http://knopwob.org/dunst/screenshots.html

Comment: @VerbalKint good to know! :)